# SC stream not working on Safari: Accept-Encoding header

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, safari, soundcloud

I'm working on [this](http://viberaid.com) SoundCloud music-streaming service.

As you enter, I make a request to SC to get some values in order to set the music player. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but Safari (both on a Mac and an iPhone) returns these errors on the console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (208248726.json, line 0)

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/208248726.json?client_id=55c6772672dd77c1147fc334e0d5ed83. Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (www.viberaid.com, line 0)
```

As I understand it, there's a problem with Safari not setting Accept-Encoding, so I found this piece of code and put it into my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Also this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
```

But neither are working, I'm getting the same response from the browser. I found [this guy](http://w3facility.org/question/safari-gets-a-403-when-trying-to-stream-through-the-soundcloud-api/) with just the exact same problem as me, but no response yet. Anyone knows what could be going wrong? I'm quite a newbie editing the htaccess and have close to zero knowledge on this, so I would love a ELI5 answer :)

Just to contextualize the problem, it's a Wordpress using JPlayer to stream music from SC with their own API.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - any luck?

Comment: Not yet, will probably put a reward on the question :/

Comment: I found out that this is just a bug on SC part, https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/27